# Enforcing the exchange criteria for two particles in a box in different states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, identical-particles

Suppose you have two identical particles (for simplicity we can think of spin 0 bosons for which are represented as a scalar wave-functions, but fermions have a similar problem) in a 1D box that ranges from x=0 to x=$\pi$. Particle 1 is in the ground state and particle 2 is in the lowest excited state.

I first assumed the the joint wavefunction is separable since the particles are in different states:
$\psi = \psi_1 \psi_2 = C sin(x_1)sin(2 x_2)$, where C is a normalization constant that makes this square-integrate to 1.

However, this *violates* the boson constraint because
$\psi(x_1, x_2) \ne \psi(x_2, x_1)$.

What is the joint wave function?

**Edit**

The solution is because *a single particle* ends up in a *superposition*. The joint function for **bosons** is:
$\psi(x_1, x_2) = C(sin(x_1) + sin(2x_1) + sin(x_2)+ sin(2x_2))$ 
For **fermions** it is $C(sin(x_1) + sin(2x_1) - sin(x_2)- sin(2x_2))$

You can't definitely say that particle A is in the ground state and B is in the excited state because you can't even say that particle A is particle A. However, you *can* say that there is one particle per state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that if $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ is not symmetric, $\psi(x_1,x_2) + \psi(x_2,x_1)$ certainly is.

This corresponds to us really not knowing whether it is the "first" particle in the ground state or the "second" particle, since they're indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

The wave function must be symmetrical because you aren't "allowed" to know which of the two bosons is in which level. If so, you were capable of distinguish one particle from the other. Indeed the problem is not that you can't know in which level they are, they aren't just in any precise level, taken alone. It's they're superposition which has a precise energy.
This superposition is described by the wave function:
$$
\psi=\frac{C}{\sqrt{2}}(\sin{x_1}\sin{2x_2}+\sin{2x_1}\sin{x_2})
$$
which is symmetrical under parity. The fact that you can say one particle is in the ground state and the other is in the lowest excited state depends on the fact that, measuring the energy of the system, you see that it's the sum of the energy of the two separated levels.